# Why am I getting this error `line 0 col 0 Bad option: '0'.` after running gulp linter task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am getting this errors

[image]

in the terminal when I run this task

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var stylish = require('jshint-stylish');

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src('public/**/*.js')
            .pipe(jshint(['.jshintignore', '.jshintrc']))
            .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});
```

here is my `.jshintrc` file

```
// NOTE: I added the .js extension to this gist so it would have syntax highlighting. This file should have NO file extension

{
    // Settings
    "passfail"      : false,  // Stop on first error.
    "maxerr"        : 100,    // Maximum error before stopping.


    // Predefined globals whom JSHint will ignore.
    "browser"       : true,   // Standard browser globals e.g. `window`, `document`.

    "node"          : false,
    "rhino"         : false,
    "couch"         : false,
    "wsh"           : true,   // Windows Scripting Host.

    "jquery"        : true,
    "ender"         : true,
    "prototypejs"   : false,
    "mootools"      : false,
    "dojo"          : false,

    "predef"        : [  // Custom globals.
        //"exampleVar",
        //"anotherCoolGlobal",
        //"iLoveDouglas"
    ],json


    // Development.
    "debug"         : false,  // Allow debugger statements e.g. browser breakpoints.
    "devel"         : true,   // Allow developments statements e.g. `console.log();`.


    // ECMAScript 5.
    "es5"           : true,   // Allow ECMAScript 5 syntax.
    "strict"        : false,  // Require `use strict` pragma  in every file.
    "globalstrict"  : false,  // Allow global "use strict" (also enables 'strict').


    // The Good Parts.
    "asi"           : true,  // Tolerate Automatic Semicolon Insertion (no semicolons).
    "laxbreak"      : true,   // Tolerate unsafe line breaks e.g. `return [\n] x` without semicolons.
    "bitwise"       : true,   // Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.).
    "boss"          : false,  // Tolerate assignments inside if, for & while. Usually conditions & loops are for comparison, not assignments.
    "curly"         : true,   // Require {} for every new block or scope.
    "eqeqeq"        : true,   // Require triple equals i.e. `===`.
    "eqnull"        : false,  // Tolerate use of `== null`.
    "evil"          : false,  // Tolerate use of `eval`.
    "expr"          : false,  // Tolerate `ExpressionStatement` as Programs.
    "forin"         : false,  // Tolerate `for in` loops without `hasOwnPrototype`.
    "immed"         : true,   // Require immediate invocations to be wrapped in parens e.g. `( function(){}() );`
    "latedef"       : true,   // Prohipit variable use before definition.
    "loopfunc"      : false,  // Allow functions to be defined within loops.
    "noarg"         : true,   // Prohibit use of `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee`.
    "regexp"        : true,   // Prohibit `.` and `[^...]` in regular expressions.
    "regexdash"     : false,  // Tolerate unescaped last dash i.e. `[-...]`.
    "scripturl"     : true,   // Tolerate script-targeted URLs.
    "shadow"        : false,  // Allows re-define variables later in code e.g. `var x=1; x=2;`.
    "supernew"      : false,  // Tolerate `new function () { ... };` and `new Object;`.
    "undef"         : true,   // Require all non-global variables be declared before they are used.


    // Personal styling preferences.
    "newcap"        : true,   // Require capitalization of all constructor functions e.g. `new F()`.
    "noempty"       : true,   // Prohibit use of empty blocks.
    "nonew"         : true,   // Prohibit use of constructors for side-effects.
    "nomen"         : true,   // Prohibit use of initial or trailing underbars in names.
    "onevar"        : false,  // Allow only one `var` statement per function.
    "plusplus"      : false,  // Prohibit use of `++` & `--`.
    "sub"           : false,  // Tolerate all forms of subscript notation besides dot notation e.g. `dict['key']` instead of `dict.key`.
    "trailing"      : true,   // Prohibit trailing whitespaces.
    "white"         : false,  // Check against strict whitespace and indentation rules.
    "indent"        : 2,       // Specify indentation spacing

    "globals": {
      "angular": false,
      "app":false
    }
}
```

any suggestions on why this could be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess but maybe your files is saved with a [BOM code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that gulp cannot recognize.

Try saving the file without BOM code with your favorite editor, eg vim:

```
vim +'set nobomb | x' /path/to/files
```

Or maybe it's the trailing: `json` in your `.jshintrc`:

```
 "predef"        : [  // Custom globals.
     //"exampleVar",
     //"anotherCoolGlobal",
     //"iLoveDouglas"
 ],json
// ^ What is this?
```

Comment: @TheUnnamed Did you try to save without BOM?

Comment: I don't get that with VIM.

Comment: @TheUnnamed Open your text editor and Press: `Save file with encoding` choose `UTF-8 without BOM`